# Wildfly 8.2.1 final failed to parse configuration

Tags: java, server, ubuntu-14.04, wildfly, wildfly-8

I have a question on wildfly server. You can see this error in the top image link. I think this problem happens because of JVM but I couldn't fix it.

My OS is **ubuntu 14.04** and I had installed **jdk 1.7 and 1.8**.

I changed default jdk to 1.7 . But I have also tried with jdk 1.8 and it was not working.

```
murat@murat-ubuntu:~/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/bin$ sh standalone.sh 
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /home/murat/wildfly-8.2.1.Final

  JAVA: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true
=========================================================================
19:35:00,280 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.3.Final
19:35:00,500 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.2.Final
19:35:00,573 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015899: WildFly 8.2.1.Final "Tweek" starting
19:35:01,133 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015956: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: JBAS014676: Failed to parse configuration
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:112) [wildfly-controller-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:331) [wildfly-server-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:259) [wildfly-controller-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_101]
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: JBAS014674: Failed to load module com.netmera.sal.jboss_ext
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.parseExtensions(ExtensionXml.java:155) [wildfly-controller-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readServerElement_1_4(StandaloneXml.java:434) [wildfly-server-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:145) [wildfly-server-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:107) [wildfly-server-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:104) [wildfly-controller-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: JBAS014674: Failed to load module
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [rt.jar:1.7.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188) [rt.jar:1.7.0_101]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.parseExtensions(ExtensionXml.java:147) [wildfly-controller-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
    ... 9 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: JBAS014674: Failed to load module
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.loadModule(ExtensionXml.java:196) [wildfly-controller-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.access$000(ExtensionXml.java:69) [wildfly-controller-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml$1.call(ExtensionXml.java:127) [wildfly-controller-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml$1.call(ExtensionXml.java:124) [wildfly-controller-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_101]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_101]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final.jar:2.1.1.Final]
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: com.netmera.sal.jboss_ext:main
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:240) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.loadModule(ExtensionXml.java:178) [wildfly-controller-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
    ... 8 more
19:35:01,139 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015957: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
19:35:01,153 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015950: WildFly 8.2.1.Final "Tweek" stopped in 8ms
```

Comment: Seems like something is wrong with your WildFly configuration file. Try to revert any custom-made changes in your `standalone.xml` and re-run the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: com.netmera.sal.jboss_ext:main`

This is the key part of the error message. On your Wildfly configuration, there's a reference to this module (`com.netmera.sal.jboss_ext`), and it couldn't be found. You probably have it defined on `standalone.xml`, or referenced by another module.